# Function to create new rows in layout isn't working properly

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, joomla3.0

Website running Joomla has a template layout specific to different product categories. In this case, we are looking at a layout for Product Category A. This product category layout is supposed to organize products in a 3-product-per-row grid.

The PHP/Jquery code gets the products for the category and then has logic to assign products to a class of "subrow" until there are 3 products in it, then it creates the next subrow and assigns it to that subrow. I am not a PHP developer so I'd like to get some input.

Issue:

- There used to be only 6 products showing under this category, which made a perfect 3x2 grid. Two subrows, three products in each. This is good.
  [image]
- A 7th product was added and it created a 3x3 grid, with the 7th product being the only one on the third row in the first position. This shows up OK visually, except in the HTML code it shows two subrows with four products in the second subrow. It should be three subrows with one product in the third subrow.
  [image]
- An 8th product was added and it created a 3x4 grid, with the 8th product being the only one on the fourth row in the first position. In the HTML code it shows three subrows, with four products in the second subrow, and one product in the third subrow. This is not good. It should have been added to second position in third row.
  [image]

**Here is the HTML with the 8th product added:**
[image: screenshot]

Below is the PHP/Jquery code for this logic. **Does anyone see any obvious problem that would be causing this to not follow the 3 products per row pattern?**

```php
callAPI("productlines/by/subcategory")
    .done(function(data) {
        var moulding = data['Product Category A']

        var maxPerRow = 3;
        var matMap = {};

        for (var i=0; i < moulding.length; i++) {
            if(i%2===0) {
                jQuery('<div/>')
                    .addClass('material-row-'+i)
            }

            var matgroup = jQuery('.material-rows');
            var subrow = matgroup.children(".subrow").last();
            if(subrow.length == 0) { subrow = jQuery("<div/>").addClass("subrow").attr("data-row",0).appendTo(matgroup); }

            if(!matMap[0]) matMap[0] = 0;
            if(++matMap[0] > maxPerRow){
                // console.log("subrow",subrow[0],"is full! making new row");
                subrow = jQuery("<div/>").addClass("subrow").appendTo(matgroup).attr("data-row",1+parseInt(subrow.attr("data-row")));
                matMap[0]=0;
            }

            popProducts(moulding[i],subrow[0])
        }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem in your code is that when you are appending new line there will be one element there, because function to append element is called after but you set in your counter (`matMap`) that there are 0 elements but it should be 1 (`matMap[0] = 1;`)

```
if(++matMap[0] > maxPerRow){
  // console.log("subrow",subrow[0],"is full! making new row");
  subrow = jQuery("<div/>").addClass("subrow").appendTo(matgroup).attr("data-row",1+parseInt(subrow.attr("data-row")));
  matMap[0]=1;
}
```

Simple example:

```js
var moulding = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var maxPerRow = 3;
var matMap = {};

for (var i = 0; i < moulding.length; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    jQuery('<div/>')
      .addClass('material-row-' + i)
  }

  var matgroup = jQuery('.material-rows');
  var subrow = matgroup.children(".subrow").last();
  if (subrow.length == 0) {
    subrow = jQuery("<div/>").addClass("subrow").attr("data-row", 0).appendTo(matgroup);
  }

  if (!matMap[0]) matMap[0] = 0;
  if (++matMap[0] > maxPerRow) {
    // console.log("subrow",subrow[0],"is full! making new row");
    subrow = jQuery("<div/>").addClass("subrow").appendTo(matgroup).attr("data-row", 1 + parseInt(subrow.attr("data-row")));
    matMap[0] = 1;
  }

  jQuery("<div/>").append("Element: " + moulding[i]).addClass("moulding-col").appendTo(subrow[0]);
  // popProducts(moulding[i],subrow[0])
}
```

```css
.subrow {
  display: flex;
}

.moulding-col {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="material-rows" />
```

Not connected with your issue but code is very ugly and you should consider improve it. I improve your function a little bit so you can check better practices (Use let, const, don't search in DOM for element that you already have (`table` for example), use more descriptive variables, etc...).

```
const moulding = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const maxItemsPerRow = 3;
const table = $('.material-rows');

for (let i = 0; i < moulding.length; i++) {
  let row = table.children(".subrow").last();
  if (!(i % maxItemsPerRow)) {
    row = $("<div/>").addClass("subrow").attr("data-row", parseInt(i / maxItemsPerRow)).appendTo(table);
  }

  $("<div/>").append("Element: " + moulding[i]).addClass("moulding-col").appendTo(row);

}
```

Comment: Right under my nose...thank you! That worked perfect. I appreciate the best practices updated code, I will forward it along.